# cannot read property 'local' of undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to save and load the radio button checked status but I am getting this error "cannot read property 'local' of undefined" here's my code

**Popup.js**

```
function SaveData(){
    alert("Save Data Enter");
    var rb1 = document.getElementById("rbox").checked;
    var rb2 = document.getElementById("rbox2").checked; 

    console.log(rb1);
    console.log(rb2);

    chrome.storage.local.set({'value': rb1}, function() {
          // Notify that we saved.
          console.log('Settings saved');
        });
}
```

rb1 and rb2 show true/false but `chrome.storage.local.set` gives error I also gave the permission of storage in menifest.json dont know why this error is coming

**menifest.json**

```
{
  ...
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>" , "storage", "webNavigation"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  ...
}
```

**Edit:2** 
[image]

**Edit-3**
 [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ovbka35q/)

Comment: Make sure that you reload your extension at `chrome://extensions/` to get the new permissions to apply.

Comment: yes I did that several times and also close all chrome processes and rerun it but nothing works

Comment: Did you save the file to the correct directory with the correct name?

Comment: yes everything is in folder named Chrome "Extension" Files name "popup.html", "popup.js", "manifest.json"

Comment: Could you make a screencast of your problem?

Comment: Have you tried 'value':'rb1'
i.e. rb1 in quotes ?

Comment: Yes still getting the same error :(

Comment: Wait. Your screenshot looks like an attached Dev Tools window. How are you opening popup.html?

Comment: I am opening popup.html from chrome browser for testing purpose but its opening with menifest.json "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

Comment: m**a**nifest.json; From Chrome browser - you mean, using the URL of the form `chrome-extension://youridhere/popup.html`? You can debug an actual popup by right-clicking the button and selecting "Inspect popup"

Comment: No, form my computer's directory C:\Users\Uzair\Desktop\Chrome Extension\popup.html   
but extension is loaded in google chrome. The reason I am opening popup.html directly is to check whether javascript is working correct or not and its not working correctly `chrome.storage.local.set` gives error even I do this `var = chrome.storage.local.set` it gives error

Comment: I only want that when I click extension popup.html will open (which have 2 radio button) that rememberd my radio button choice

Comment: When you open popup.html directly from the filesystem, it gets run as a web page and does not have access to Chrome Extension APIs. You have to run it by clicking the browserAction.

Comment: Ops sorry   
now its working fine from browserAction